# Accidentally remove own user account on Windows 10

Tags: windows, users

While writing script that automatically removes unauthorized users from a virtual machine and testing it on my host, I managed to accidentally remove my own user (without removing files). I tried creating a new user of the same name but it created a separate user directory for the new user. Is there any way to recreate this user and have it use my old files as the home directory?

Comment: Please check if the following link is helpful with you:https://www.easeus.com/pc-transfer/how-to-transfer-data-from-one-user-account-to-another-in-windows-10.html  https://appuals.com/how-to-create-a-new-user-account-and-transfer-all-the-data-to-it/

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues here that explains what happens here.

1. Every user, even if they have the same username, will have a unique ID attached to it. Because of this, they are always going to be treated as different users. So deleting, then creating a new identical user is impossible.
2. Deleting your own user while using your own user cannot delete files that are currently in use, and thus it cannot create your user folder because it was in use too. So a new folder is always created. Also because of point 1.

So because your user now has a new ID, you will have to manually copy the files from the old profile to the new profile folder. You can then delete the old folder, but the new folder will still be used regardless of what you do as it is stored like that in the registry. It will be a huge hassle for little gain to get it fixed.